# Plot an HTML Element in DIV using D3 JS

Tags: html, d3.js, plot

I am new to D3 JS. Is there a working sample that uses D3 to plot a DIV or any other HTML Element in the SVG area. Let's assume that I will do a scatter plot of several DIVs in the plot area. content of the DIV will be dynamic.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
There is foreignObject element that allows you to embed HTML elements into SVG.

You can read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject